# return_to_string in DetailView

Tags: django

I'm trying to `render_to_string` a partial in my DetailView, in order to send the rendered html back through json for ajax to pick up.

My views.py look like this:

```
class ProfileDetails(DetailView):
    model = UserProfile

    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        response_data = {}
    response_data['content'] = render_to_string("profile/userprofile_detail/content.html", self.get_context_data())
    if request.is_ajax():
        return HttpResponse(
             json.dumps(response_data),
            content_type="application/json"
        )
    else:
        return get_object_or_404(
            UserProfile, 
            user__username=self.kwargs['username'],
        )
```

This does not work, because I just get this attribute error:

> 'ProfileDetails' object has no attribute 'object'

I did search online on how to do this, but for my situation where I also need to use custom url parameters, this does not suffice.

How can I make this work with how I have it currently set up? My only goal here is sending the rendered partial to ajax, but I need to actually render it first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you're overriding the get_object() method correctly. Your implementation can return an HttpResponse object which the DetailView doesn't seem to be able to and display properly. Even if it *could* serialize the HttpResponse object, your code is trying to **display the field/values of the HttpResponse object you're constructing**, when what you really want is for the view to return the HttpResponse object itself. What you want to do is remove all the ajax detection, serialization, and response generation logic in the get_object method and move it into an override of the view's get() method something to the effect of:

```
def get(self, request, *arg, **kwargs):
    if request.is_ajax():
       # Generate and return your HttpResponse object here
    return super(ProfileDetails, self).get(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

The return value of the get method is supposed to be an HttpResponse object which the base View class knows how to handle. I encourage you to review the documentation for class-based views to get a better understanding of how they process requests/responses.

Comment: Remember that I am using a custom url pattern for this, which looks like this: `url(r'^(?P<username>[-\w]+)/$', ProfileDetails.as_view(), name='profile-details'),` So I need to keep the `get_object_or_404` somehow and still render the partial and send through json.

Comment: in your example get_object_or_404 only gets called in the case of non-ajax requests. In my suggestion get_object_or_404 would still get called (by the super call)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that, the super thing. I have looked at the documentation and nowhere can I find anything related to class based views with the term "super". Care to elaborate a bit?

Comment: super() is a python built-in which calls the current class's parent class implementation of the specified method. The get() method is a method implemented by the base View class. In the case of the example, the get method override will first check to see if the request is an AJAX request, if it is you can return your own custom HttpResponse; If it's not an ajax request, just call DetailView's get method implementation (e.g. handle the request as usual). In the scenario where the request is not an AJAX request your get_object() method will be called as-usual.

Comment: Documentation for get(): https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/ref/class-based-views/base/#view
This page explains super and inheritance in python pretty well: http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex44.html